# Math formula for crystal glass resonance

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, resonance

For a music therapy experiment, I have to use several crystal glasses with water and different cylindrical shapes, and make them vibrate and produce different sounds. Is there a math formula that binds together the radius of the glass, the level of the water (or the volume occupied), and the frequency that produces the sound? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Science behind the singing wine glass](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39263/)

Comment: Your question is a duplicate, though I have to admit the previous question hasn't got any really good answers. You might be interested in this paper on [singing wineglasses](http://mafija.fmf.uni-lj.si/seminar/files/2010_2011/Seminar-Singing_Wineglasses.pdf). There isn't a simple formula to predict the resonant frequency.

Comment: I suspected it wasn't a simple issue, but the document you linked are very interesting and surely it will be helpful for my problem, thanks indeed @JohnRennie